# compiling C++ mac, look for header files not found

Tags: c++, macos

Based on this tutorial:
http://syskall.com/how-to-roll-out-your-own-javascript-api-with/index.html/

I am trying to compile a C++ program on a mac, however the includes in my C++ file are not being found. I have the following directory structure:

```
myProj/
  |-- deps/  # third party code
  |   `-- v8
  `-- src/ 
      `-- myProj.cpp
```

in the myProj.cpp, I have several includes:

```
#include <include/v8.h>
```

so when i go to compile, I use the following:

```
g++ src/jsnotify.cpp -Ideps/v8/include
```

the deps/v8/include directory clearly has v8.h, but it still shows up as not found. is -I the correct flag for mac? I am also having trouble in linking:

```
g++ src/jsnotify.cpp -Ideps/v8/ -Ldeps/v8/ -lv8 -lpthread -v
```

the -lv8 causes:

```
ld: library not found for -lv8
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at exactly what you're telling the compiler:

```
#include <include/v8.h>
```

"open the file "include/v8.h"

```
g++ src/jsnotify.cpp -Ideps/v8/include
```

"When trying to find files to include, search in deps/v8/include"

So, the obvious question: does `deps/v8/include` contain `include/v8.h`? In other words, do you have the file `deps/v8/include/include/v8.h`?

Answer (score 0):

As you have it, the pre-processor is trying to resolve #include `<include/v8.h>` to `deps/v8/include/include/v8.h`.

Change your include to be:

```
#include <v8.h>
```

Or change your compiler command line to:

```
g++ src/jsnotify.cpp -Ideps/v8
```

Either option is likely to work - but if v8.h also specifies additional include files specified by prepending the "include" path (e.g. `#include <include/foo.h>`) then the second option is more likely to work.